# weird artifacts while making a kaleidoscope

Tags: rendering, light, world

I'm fiddling around with a kaleidoscope, but there are some weird artifacts in the render. The artifacts are the ripped lines coming from the ball and you can clearly see faces of something(color corresponds to world settings). I've set bounces very high so I don't think that that is the problem.
[image: render]
The render

[image]
My setup

Comment: I think your question is a little unclear as to what the problem is visually—the raised gridlines on the ball are what is undesirable?

Comment: No, the ripped white lines and the black background where individual faces are visible